# PHP usort Before While loop

Tags: php, sorting

I have a paging class that runs a query and returns only the specified page of rows.

Here is the function in concern. It works great, but my issue is that I want to add sorting functionality.

```
private function GetData($Query, $PageNumber, $RowsPerPage) {

    $stmt = dbQuery($Query, 'static');
    $this->TotalNumOfRows = sqlsrv_num_rows($stmt);
    $this->_NumberOfPages = ceil($this->TotalNumOfRows / $this->_RowsPerPage);
    $offset = ($PageNumber - 1) * $RowsPerPage;
    $rows = [];
    $i = 0;
    while (($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_BOTH, SQLSRV_SCROLL_ABSOLUTE, $offset + $i)) && $i < $RowsPerPage) {
        $rows[] = $row;
        $i++;
    }
    $this->CurrentPageNumOfRows = $i;

    return $rows;
}
```

I have a sorting fdunction that I use to sort my arrays by column index.

```
function gfSortArray($a, $b) {
        $pSort = gfGetVar('pSort', 0);
        $pDir = gfGetVar('pDir', 'desc');

        if ($pDir == 'asc') {
            return strnatcmp($a[$pSort], $b[$pSort]);
        }
        else {
            return strnatcmp($b[$pSort], $a[$pSort]);
        }
}
```

I can add the function to my paging class, but the issue is that it only sorts the specified rows. 1-100 for example. But I need to sort the entire array before the while loop so that it sorts properly.

Here is the function with the sorting.

```
private function GetData($Query, $PageNumber, $RowsPerPage) {

    $stmt = dbQuery($Query, 'static');
    $this->TotalNumOfRows = sqlsrv_num_rows($stmt);
    $this->_NumberOfPages = ceil($this->TotalNumOfRows / $this->_RowsPerPage);
    $offset = ($PageNumber - 1) * $RowsPerPage;
    $rows = [];
    $i = 0;
    while (($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_BOTH, SQLSRV_SCROLL_ABSOLUTE, $offset + $i)) && $i < $RowsPerPage) {
        $rows[] = $row;
        $i++;
    }
    $this->CurrentPageNumOfRows = $i;

    //sorting
    usort($rows, ['Paging', 'gfSortArray']);

    return $rows;
}
```

Question:
**Is there a way to possibly sort the SQL_SRV_QUERY result before the While Loop?**

Comment: If you know the field names you want to sort by, you can alter the query. Example: suppose my query is "select name, age from ....". I want to sort by age. I can actually use "select * from ($query) order by age" as the query and it comes out presorted.

Comment: Yes I do that currently when I have dynamic sql, I use the usort when its a basic query. I wanted to add usort to my paging class so I dont have to write a switch to alter my sort order clause.